# While displaying the items from the cart class in a a jsp file the values are overriding previous one (SESSION)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm working on adding multiple dish id, quantity and food description.

**Cart.java**

```
package com.hotelordering;
public class Cart{
    int quantity;
    int menuid;
    String fooddesc;

public void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity=quantity;
}
public int getQuantity(){

    return quantity;
}
public void setMenuId(int menuid){
    this.menuid=menuid;
}
public int getMenuId(){
    return menuid;
}
public void setFoodDesc(String fooddesc){

    this.fooddesc=fooddesc;
}
public String getFoodDesc(){
    return fooddesc;
    }
}
```

**AddToCart.jsp (Getting paramater values from submission page)**

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="checkCart.jsp">
    <%  
        ArrayList<Cart> list= new ArrayList<Cart>();
        Cart cart = new Cart();
        Enumeration<String> parameters=request.getParameterNames();

        while(parameters.hasMoreElements())
            {
                String value=parameters.nextElement();

                if(value.equals("quantity"))
                {
                    try{
                        String[] q=request.getParameterValues(value);
                        for(String quant: q)
                        {
                            int quantity=Integer.parseInt(quant);
                            cart.setQuantity(quantity);
                            list.add(cart);
                            session.setAttribute("quantity",list);
                        }
                    }

                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if(value.equals("menuid"))
                {
                try{
                String[] m=request.getParameterValues(value);
                for(String menu: m)
                {
                    int menuid=Integer.parseInt(menu);
                    cart.setMenuId(menuid);
                    list.add(cart);
                    session.setAttribute("menuid",list);
                }
                }   
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   

                }
                else
                {
                try{
                    String[] fooddesc=request.getParameterValues(value);
                    for(String food: fooddesc)
                    {
                        cart.setFoodDesc(food);
                        list.add(cart);
                        session.setAttribute("fooddesc",list);
                    }
                }   
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
        }

        out.println("Added to cart !");
    %>
        <input type="submit" value="Check cart"><br>
    </form>
    <form action="displayCategory.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Add more item"><br>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**checkCart.jsp** 
Displaying `quantity`, `menuid` and `description` from `ArrayList` but it is overriding previous value and repeating the last entered values again

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" %>

<form action="test.jsp" method="post">

<%
    Cart cart=new Cart();

 ArrayList<Cart> list = (ArrayList<Cart>)session.getAttribute("quantity");

    for(Cart c:list)
    {
        out.println("Quantity" + c.getQuantity() + "<Br>");
        out.println("Menu id: " + c.getMenuId() + "<Br>");
        out.println("Food description: " + c.getFoodDesc() + "<Br>");
    }




%>



<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

*OUTPUT*
[image]

Comment: Debug it, you will get the solution by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The list value setting(`session.setAttribute`) should be outside for loop in the code above. 
Similarly for other cases .
Since you are setting list value inside for loop itself final value alone getting added. And you also need to have new Cart object initialized for each object inside for loop. Your new Cart initialization should be inside for loop

```
   for(String quant: q) {
      cart=new Cart();
      int quantity=Integer.parseInt(quant);
      cart.setQuantity(quantity);
      list.add(cart);
}
    session.setAttribute("quantity",list);
```

Comment: I tried that already but its not working. It throws NullPointerException.


  [1]: https://imgur.com/a/eorqo6p

Comment: can you post full log trace. I am able to see some number format exception also